# Preserving whitespace in text replacement using python 3

Tags: python, regex, replace, text-files

I am trying to automate replacement of lines of source code text in a file with their corresponding string parts translated. 
For this I have created a workflow to get two data structures which have all corresponding text for a specific line. However, since my source-code file is in coffee script (white-space is significant!) the code below is unable to detect the strings in the lines (because of variable white-space in the beginning of the code parts). Is there a way to use some wildcard or a way to preserve the white-space as-it-is and do the replacement:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import fileinput

# List of strings to be replaced in the source
sourceList = ['name: "My House",','name: "His House",']
# List of target translated strings matching index values with the sourceList
targetList = ['name: "私の家",','name: "彼の家",']

# Loops over sourceList and performs in-place replacement with the value at corresponding index in targetList
for i, val in enumerate(sourceList):
    for line in fileinput.input("seed-staging.coffee", inplace=True):
        print(line.replace(sourceList[i], targetList[i]), end = '') # End part is essential to not get default newline from print
```

The aim is to find the line, replace it **preserving the white space of indent-levels on the left.**

Update: Adding the source and desired output sample for Coffee Script.

```
exports.locations = [
    {
        "name": "My House",
         ...
    }
```

should turn to:

```
exports.locations = [
    {
        "name": "私の家",
         ...
    }
```

The key is to preserve the white-space.

Comment: Add the coffee file you are working with (or a stripped-down sample version of it) to your question. Also add the desired output for that sample.

Comment: Done. Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: What's your actual output? As far as I can tell, this should work.

Comment: In the actual output, the string in source isn't being detected at all. Nothing's getting replaced :( and I thought it is because there is white-space in the beginning.

Comment: Oops. It works. There were quotes around keys too in the key value pairs. Sorry for not realizing it!